# Как из фрагмента поменять цвет кнопки в активности

Tags: java, android

Имею кнопки в активности, по нажатию на кнопки я открываю фрагменты. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при открытии фрагмента в нем срабатывал код вроде

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable..);
```

Пробовал прописывать во всех OnCreate`ах фрагмента это:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable..);
```

но приложение крашилось с ошибкой на 2 строке из примера

Comment: С какой ошибкой? Ошибку тоже добавьте в вопрос

Comment: В фрагменте надо работать с onViewCreated, а не с onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать интерфейс между фрагментом и активностью и в определенный момент передавать информацию об изменении цвета кнопки. Делаем интерфейс:

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass();
}
```

в методе фрагмента `OnAttach()`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;
}
```

как вы могли понять `dataPasser` это глобальная переменная. В нужный момент вызывает метод интерфейса:

```
public void passData() {
    dataPasser.onDataPass();
}
```

так же необходимо реализовать интерфейс в целевой активности `implements OnDataPass`:

```
@Override
public void onDataPass() {
    Log.d("LOG","change color");
}
```

Comment: Получилось передать информацию, но когда я пытаюсь изменить изображение картинки приложение крашится с ошибками на строках изменения картинки. Причем вызывая функцию с их изменением в onCreate все работает

Comment: ну по логике со стороны интерфейса все должно быть нормально, изображение возможно некорректное передаёте

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278462/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-someevent